# Can Avalonia host Window with Native handle?

Tags: c#, opengl, avaloniaui, avalonia

There is an application which consists or two parts - WPF user interface and C++ dll with math and Opengl graphics. The WPF user interface has WindowsFormsHost  with a Windows Forms Label in it. The handle of the label is used to draw graphics using Opengl.

Now the application should be made cross-platform. Avalonia is a good choice as a user interface part, but unfortunately I did not managed to find if it is possible to embed a window with native handle in an Avalonia window?

Is there something like WindowsFormsHost of WPF or another control?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

1. a class inherited from NativeControlHost should be created.
2. CreateNativeControlCore function should be overriden;
3. in the function the following code should be placed:

> var piHandle = base.CreateNativeControlCore(parent);
> //this is the handle
> m_Handle = piHandle.Handle;

As the result a window with the handle m_Handle will be created.

Comment: Accept this answer, so that people know that this works.